# Debug custom font issues on API

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-font, android-fonts

I was using a custom font `Aspira` in my Android application, but all of sudden it stopped working, most probably after I configured `TestFairy`.

I have taken off `TestFairy` configuration but still I could not get my custom font `Aspira` working on Emulator and external mobile devices (used for testing).

However in `Android Studio` preview window it shows the text with custom font style. Wonder why not it appears in Emulator or mobile devices.

Occasionally runs on emulator (`oreo` version).

**If I set font programatically then it only works, through `XML` it does not work.**

---

*Note: I am using `.ttf` font file, and have also tried to change the font file just for testing, but the other/new font also does not work in Emulator/testing devices.*

Any help appreciated in advance assisting to trace or debug the issue.

Comment: try clean build

Comment: Have tried already, but no success.